# Too old to migrate question for Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, migration

"[Email password fails with & in it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/81724/23812)" is specifically about configuring Exim. As Exim is server-side software and not web-specific I'd think it would fit better on Server Fault.

When trying to flag as off-topic it's marked "too old to migrate". Should we still look at migrating it anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is no way to migrate questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) (even for moderators).   Migration is disabled for old questions because:

- It can cause large reputation changes
- It prevents mass migration of old questions

The only thing that we can suggest is that the user re-asks the question on the other site.  If they do so, we could edit a link into the question on this site if they ask for it.